# Getting a blob image works in chrome but is inconsistent in edge (React 18)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

So I have a function that runs on a 5 second interval that fetches a jpeg image from the backend and shows it to the user. It works perfectly in chrome, but in edge, every other call (so about 50% of the calls) fail with no clear indication of what's going wrong. It doesn't give any status code; the blob just fails to load and says "net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". I've researched this specific error but it seems like there's multiple different things that can cause them, and none of them fit within my code and scope, so I'm not sure.

The function to get the image every 5 seconds:

```
export function useImage({
    mac,
    timeout,
    refresh,
}: {
    mac: string;
    timeout: number;
    refresh: boolean;
}) {
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    const [firstImageRequested, setFirstImageRequested] = useState(false);

    const getImage = React.useCallback(
        function getImage(mac: string): void {
            getCameraImage(mac).then((res) => {
                res.blob()
                    .then((blob: Blob) => {
                        const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        setImage(objectUrl);
                    })
                    .catch(console.error);
            });
        },
        [setImage]
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        let timeoutHandle: any;

        // Releasing object URL
        // MORE INFO ON WHY: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Memory_management
        if (image) {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(image);
        }

        // Immediately fetch the image if we haven't asked for the first image yet
        if (!firstImageRequested) {
            getImage(mac);
            setFirstImageRequested(true);
        }

        // If we've asked for the first image want to refresh, set a timeout
        if (refresh && firstImageRequested) {
            timeoutHandle = setTimeout(() => {
                getImage(mac);
            }, timeout);
        }
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
        };
    }, [
        mac,
        refresh,
        timeout,
        image,
        getImage,
        firstImageRequested,
        setFirstImageRequested,
    ]);

    return [image];
}
```

Where it's used:

```
const CameraCard: React.FunctionComponent<{
    camera: CameraStatus;
}> = ({ camera }) => {
    const img = useRef(null);
    const imgContainer = useRef(null);
    const { mac, name, isOnline, isConfigured, status, type } = camera;
    var [newRefresh, setNewRefresh] = useState(true);
    var idCam = 'refresh_' + mac;

    const [imageUrl] = useImage({
        mac: camera.mac,
        timeout: 5000,
        refresh: newRefresh,
    });

    const showPlaceholderImageOnError = (err) => {
        img.current.src = placeholderImage;
    };

    // Calculate the a max height value so that the table's height matches the
    // height of the camera image
    const sidebarMaxHeight = (() => {
        const currentImageWidth =
            imgContainer.current && imgContainer.current.offsetWidth;

        if (currentImageWidth) {
            const num = currentImageWidth / 1.33333333;
            return `${num + 18}px`;
        } else {
            return `${250}px`;
        }
    })();

    const statusClassnames = classNames('db-camera-status', {
        'camera-online': status === 'online',
        'camera-warning': status === 'warn',
        'camera-offline': status === 'offline',
    });

    return (
        <Card className="camera-card">
            <CardBody>
                <div className="row" style={{ maxHeight: sidebarMaxHeight }}>
                    <div className="col-md-7">
                        <div ref={imgContainer}>
                            {status === 'offline' ? (
                                <img
                                    ref={img}
                                    className="db-camera-image"
                                    src={placeholderImage}
                                    alt="Question mark"
                                />
                            ) : (
                                <img
                                    ref={img}
                                    src={imageUrl}
                                    className="db-camera-image"
                                    onError={showPlaceholderImageOnError}
                                    alt={`Camera ${mac}`}
                                />
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    );
};
```

In chrome, it works as intended, but in edge, every other call fails:
[image]

I'm not sure why the behavior is different between browsers and I'm not sure how to go about diagnosing this issue and fixing it. Any help is much appreciated.